# The global dimension of the localization ring of a complete local ring at a prime ideal of its subring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R\subseteq S$ be a finite ring extension such that $R$ and $S$ are both complete noetherian local domains. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$ and denote by $\mathfrak{q}_1,\ldots, \mathfrak{q}_n$ all the prime ideals of $S$ that lie over $\mathfrak{p}$.

Assume that $R$ is regular and the local rings $S_{\mathfrak{q_1}}, \ldots, S_{\mathfrak{q}_n}$ are all of finite global dimension,  can we deduce  that $S_\mathfrak{p}$ is of finite global dimension?

Any comments are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. If global dimension of $A_P$ is at most $n$ for all maximal ideals $P$ of $A$, then global dimension of $A$ is at most $n$. In your case, take $A=S_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $n$ to be the maximum global dimensions of $S_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$.

Comment: @Mohan, Thanks a lot.